# What are the requirements to unlock certain G3* quests?

Tags: monster-hunter-4-ultimate

There are certain 3* Elder Hall (G3*) quests that are only available after you unlock them somehow. Ten of them are available through deciphering scrolls, but there are some others that are only unlocked if you fulfill some other unspecified requirement.

For example, I know the [Advanced: Fur Fixation](http://kiranico.com/index.php/en/mh4u/quest/guild/10/advanced-fur-fixation) (furious rajang) quest's requirements are to kill a certain number of "Fanged Beasts", but I don't know how many.

What are the requirements for the remaining G3* quests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taken from [gaijinhunter](http://gaijinhunter.tumblr.com/post/113484374222/unlocking-special-g3-quests)

- Golden Rajang: Hunt 80+ Fanged Beasts (Kecha Wacha family, Lagombi, Congalal family, Rajang all count). The Hunt-a-Thon for Kecha in the village is a good wa y to unlock this fast.
- Apex Diablos: Hunt 15+ Diablos/Black Diablos
- Apex Tidal Najarala: Hunt 25 Najarala/Tidal Najarala
- Apex Gravios: Hunt 35+ Gravios/Black Gravios
- Apex Tigrex: Hunt 40+ Tigrex/Brute Tigrex/Molten Tigrex
- Apex Zinogre: Hunt 40+ Zinogre/Sygian Zinogre

Answer (score 2):

I'm not G-Rank 3, but I believe you might be looking for the quests;

> Operations Tongue Twister, Fire Extinguister, Windbreaker, Tigrex Tamer, Rust Remover, Swordbreaker, Lionheart (Chameleos, Teostra, Kushala Daora, Apex Tigrex, Rust Kushala Daora, Apex Seregios, Apex Rajang)

If so, these quests do require other quests that must be completed. (The below list is in the same order as above.

> Advanced: A Formless Friend, Advanced: Quagmire Quarrel/Advanced: Emperor of Embers, Advanced:Quagmire Quarrel/ Advanced: Storm of Steel, Advanced: Quagmire Quarrel

The above quests are to unlock the first 3 **Operation** quests. The others are as follows;

> Advanced: Fury on the Mount/ Advanced: Winds of Discord/ Advanced: 1001 Shards/ Advanced: Beyond Brawn.

I am not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but I thought it would help otherwise.

[Source](http://kiranico.com/en/mh4u/quest/guild)

Comment: I meant the ones like Advanced: Rhapsody in Rime, Tigrex in Effect, Fur Fixation, Winds of Discord, etc. The other advanced quests that aren't from a scroll. How do you unlock those? Maybe I should list them in the OP...

Comment: Oh, sorry as I stated before, im not G 3, so I had no idea about the "Scrolls" business.